# Show parent category in URL of subcategory archive page

Tags: categories, permalinks

I currently have my permalink structure for posts as `/%category%/%postname%/` so my permalinks look like `/category/sub-category/post-name/`.

However, the archive pages for these subcategories instead have the format `/sub-category/` instead of the desired `/category/sub-category/`.

Anyone know how I'd go about doing this without resorting to creating individual pages like [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538265/wordpress-show-parent-category-and-subcategory-name-in-subcategory-archive-url) did back in 2013 (which seems to be the only other post with this specific query, although correct me if I'm wrong).